# Trigonometric problem: $2^{\sin{x}} + 2^{\cos{x}} \ge 2^{(1-1/{\sqrt2})}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, means

Show that:
$$\large2^{\sin{x}} + 2^{\cos{x}} \ge 2^\left({1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$$

This looks like an am gm problem to me where we should be using the fact that am is more that or equal to gm but I am having problem solving this equation after this:

$\large\left(2^{\sin{x}} + 2^{\cos{x}}\right)/2 \ge \sqrt{2^{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}}$

Please solve the sum step wise. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the am-gm inequality,
\begin{align}
\frac{2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}}{2}
&\ge 2^{\frac{1}{2}(\sin x+\cos x)}\\
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides of the inequality by $2$ yields
$$2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}\ge2\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}(\sin x+\cos x)}$$
Since $\color\red{\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)}$, we have
\begin{align}
RHS
&=2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{2}(\sin{x}+\cos{x})}\\
&=2^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x+\pi/4)}\\
&\ge2^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}
as $-1\le \sin(x+\pi/4)\le 1.$
Hence
$$\color\red{2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}}\ge 2^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x+\pi/4)}\ge \color\red{2^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}}$$

Comment: Sir I can't understand the last step of the solution .

Comment: 2⋅212(sinx+cosx)=21+12√sin(x+π/4)≥21−12√
Hence
2sinx+2cosx≥21−12√

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Deriving to find the extrema, you get
$$\ln2\cos x\ 2^{\sin x}-\ln2\sin x\ 2^{\cos x}=0,$$
which has the obvious solutions $\sin x=\cos x$, i.e. $x=\frac\pi4+k\pi$.

The corresponding function values are $2\ 2^{\pm1/\sqrt2}$, of which the smallest is $2^{(1-1/\sqrt2)}$. The bound is tight.

(Remains to prove that these are the only roots.)

Comment: I am sorry I don't know extrema so I can't understand your answer.